# How to resize ggplot inside a function without saving the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to resize a plot created within a function but it's not working.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(magrittr)

plot_exons  <- function(exons_df, exon_start, exon_end) {
  d = data.frame(
    x1 = exon_start,
    x2 = exon_end,
    y1 = c(1.5, 1.5),
    y2 = c(2, 2),
    t = paste0('Exon ' , seq(1, nrow(exons_df))),
    label = paste0('Exon ' , seq(1, nrow(exons_df)))
  )
  
  d %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot() +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "(kbp)", scales::pretty_breaks(n = 8)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.6,
               size = 20,
               alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_rect(
      data = d,
      mapping = aes(
        xmin = x1,
        xmax = x2,
        ymin = 1.5,
        ymax = 1.8,
        label = label
      ),
      color = "black",
      fill = "#56B4E9"
    ) +
    ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
      data = d,
      aes(
        x = x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2,
        y = 1.8,
        label = label,
      ),
      size = 10,
      force_pull   = 0,
      # do not pull toward data points
      nudge_y      = 0.05,
      direction    = "x",
      angle        = 90,
      vjust        = 0,
      segment.size = 0.2,
    ) +
    ylim(1.5, 2.2) +
    xlab("(kbp)") +
    ylab("") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none",
      panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 30),
      axis.ticks.length =  unit(10, "pt"),
      text = element_text(size = 30),
      panel.border = element_blank()
    )
  
}

start = c(1, 5, 8, 14, 19, 25)
end = c(3, 6, 12, 16, 22, 30)
label = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

regions = tibble::tibble(label, start, end)

plot_exons(regions, regions$start, regions$end)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: force_pull
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

but I want to resize the plot (height = 15cm, width= 70cm) inside the function. So, I tried

```
ggdraw()+
       draw_plot(p,x=0,y=0,width=70,height = 15)
```

and also adding before the plot

```
options(repr.plot.width = 70, repr.plot.height = 10)
```

but none worked except using `ggsave('fig.jpg', width = 70, height = 18, units = "cm" )`.

[image]

How can I produce the same plot (resize the plot within the function without saving the plot), please?

Comment: You mean, have `ggplot` automatically resize your plotting window?? cm doesn't make sense as a unit unless you are saving the plot. I believe `cowplot::draw_plot` is intended for subplots, i.e., if you want the plot to take up less than the full graphics device. If you want to make a graphic device of a specific size, I think you need to be looking at things like `?x11`

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas. I tried both `dev.new(width = 80, height = 15)` and `x11(width = 80, height = 15)` but none of it worked.